# How to find the common table names for EOS

Tags: eosjs

Learning EOSJS right now, I wonder how to get the commonly used table names by EOSIO for eos.getTableRows method? It seems to be a very basic thing yet I can't seem to find a reference for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the table names that can be queried, check out the **eosio.system contract's abi**.

### Tables:

- producers
- global
- voters
- userres
- delband
- rammarket
- refunds
- namebids

---

Source | https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.abi#L526

```
"tables": [{
      "name": "producers",
      "type": "producer_info",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : ["owner"],
      "key_types" : ["uint64"]
    },{
      "name": "global",
      "type": "eosio_global_state",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : [],
      "key_types" : []
    },{
      "name": "voters",
      "type": "voter_info",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : ["owner"],
      "key_types" : ["account_name"]
    },{
      "name": "userres",
      "type": "user_resources",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : ["owner"],
      "key_types" : ["uint64"]
    },{
      "name": "delband",
      "type": "delegated_bandwidth",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : ["to"],
      "key_types" : ["uint64"]
    },{
      "name": "rammarket",
      "type": "exchange_state",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : ["supply"],
      "key_types" : ["uint64"]
    },{
      "name": "refunds",
      "type": "refund_request",
      "index_type": "i64",
      "key_names" : ["owner"],
      "key_types" : ["uint64"]
    },{
       "name": "namebids",
       "type": "namebid_info",
       "index_type": "i64",
       "key_names" : ["newname"],
       "key_types" : ["account_name"]
    }
   ],
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate that! I was testing the table names in other contracts, such as the eos.token one https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.abi, it doesn't seem to be working for me. I wonder how to make use of those..